# How to add multiple theme attributes to the same activity on Android Manifest?

Tags: android, coding-style, themes, android-manifest

I have an android manifest with an activity that I want to apply to styles to:

```
 <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="Language" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar>
```

Is how it looks right now, but while keeping the NoTitleBar attribute, I would like to add this attribute as well:

```
android:style/Theme.Light"
```

But I'm just so new to Android that I can't figure it out.

Please help!

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I am trying to do right now.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You cannot have more than one theme applied at once in your manifest.

I believe there is a theme `Theme.Light.NoTitleBar` that will do what you want - but I will show you below how you can easily do this yourself and customize more.

What you need to do is create a theme which has either `Theme.NoTitleBar` or `Theme.Light` as it's parent and customizes the bits you want -- in this case the easiest way is to create a theme with `Theme.Light` as it's parent and just hide the title bar (rather than have the `Theme.NoTitleBar` as the parent and then have to make everything light which is much harder!).

You can do this with the following code in your `themes.xml` file in the `values` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <!-- use the Android Light theme as the base for our own theme -->
    <style name="MySuperTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">

        <!-- hide the Window Title -->
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>

        <!-- You could change the scrollbar, checkbox style, anything! -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

Then use `android:theme="@style/MySuperTheme"` for your activity (or you could even apply it to your whole application by placing it on the application element -- if you apply a style to an individual activity and have one set for the whole application as well then the style of the individual activity will be the one shown).

Take a look at the Android [themes.xml](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml) for a list of all the things you can customize in your own theme.

You can also look at all of the [Android styles](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/styles.xml) to see how they are done.

Comment: I don't have themes.xml in the values folder

Answer (score 5):

You'll need at least 2 styles, best inheriting from base styles, e.g. [`Theme.Material`](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html) variants, or if you use `appcompat` then `Theme.AppCompat` variants. In each style override values such as colours, drawables etc with theme-specific values.

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- original theme attributes -->
    ...
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- alternative theme attributes -->
    ...
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
</style>
```

This will be sufficient if you only use framework or `appcompat` attributes (e.g. `colorAccent`, `android:textColorPrimary` etc) in your layouts. But if you need your own attributes (e.g. a drawable with color that is different per theme), then you will need to define [custom attributes](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html#customattr).

**values/attrs.xml**

```
<attr name="themedMenuStoryDrawable" format="reference" />
<attr name="themedMenuCommentDrawable" format="reference" />
...
```

Specify theme-specific values for your custom attributes:

**values/styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- original theme attributes -->
    ...
    <item name="themedMenuStoryDrawable">@drawable/ic_subject_white_24dp</item>
    <item name="themedMenuCommentDrawable">@drawable/ic_mode_comment_white_24dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- alternative theme attributes -->
    ...
    <item name="themedMenuStoryDrawable">@drawable/ic_subject_black_24dp</item>
    <item name="themedMenuCommentDrawable">@drawable/ic_mode_comment_black_24dp</item>
</style>
```

Then refer to your custom attributes with `?attr/` prefix in layouts, menus etc:

**menu/my_menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@id/menu_comment"
        android:icon="?attr/themedMenuCommentDrawable" />
    <item android:id="@id/menu_story"
        android:icon="?attr/themedMenuStoryDrawable" />
</menu>
```

Check out [my blog post](https://hidroh.github.io/2015/02/25/support-multiple-themes-android-app-part-2/) for the complete guide.

Comment: Is Theme.AppCombat an inbuilt theme in Android. +1 for nice explanation ?

Comment: Hi it's not part of the SDK, but part of support library: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html