# how to start a emulator with notitlebar style by default?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run an android application in an emulator with no Titlebar default. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to incorporate this into a theme, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5998565/how-to-add-multiple-theme-attributes-to-the-same-activity-on-android-manifest).

From code, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591036/how-to-hide-the-title-bar-for-an-activity-in-xml-with-existing-custom-theme) for the `onCreate` answer:

```
//Remove title bar
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with the this.requestWindowsFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); With this you can make your program full-screen-sized:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```